# CSRF token mismatch in Laravel / Angular app

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

In an app which mixes Laravel and Angular, I have this persistent `CSRF token mismatch` error coming up when calling a route from an Angular service. This is more or less how it's set up:

**ROUTES**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'] ], function () {

   // non-auth routes (e.g. signup, login) ...

   Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

       Route::get('w/{ignore?}', function () { return view('writer.index');})
         ->where('ignore', '.*');

       Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'doc/open', 'Controller@openItem');
   });
});
```

The `writer.index` view shows up fine without token error (the user has been authenticated).

The **VIEW** includes:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

and

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) {
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        if (token) {
            return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

From **Angular**, a service is producing a request to the `doc/open` route over `$http.post` which returns the `token mismatch error`.

I checked the headers and the `$http.post` did in fact send over a value for `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. However, this header value does not match the `XSRF-TOKEN` value in the cookie. If that's the mismatch, why is it occurring?

Comment: You dont need to setup for angular, because it already sends x-xsrf that is recieved from Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-xsrf-token

Comment: @naneri thanks. but if I remove it, I still get the error though.

Comment: could you check in dev tools does angular send any headers during AJAX calls? By the way which versions of Angular are you using?

Comment: @naneri Angular v1.2.12 and it's sending X-XSRF-TOKEN and cookie (which includes XRSF-TOKEN, and is different from X-XSRF-TOKEN)

Comment: are you using route groups ?

Comment: can you include complete `route.php` in the question

Comment: @jaysingkar see updated question. there are some more route groups but those are only prefix related

Comment: just a suggestion. can you once try removing the routes in `auth` route group and adding the directly to `web` route group, as `auth` is not a middleware group. You can then add `auth` middleware to each route where necessary

Comment: I think, this would solve your problem. Let me know if it does

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5.3, this is made simple with Passport package. I was having the same trouble with Angular resource requests. I fixed it by installing Passport via composer and adding the following lines to

```
app\Http\Kernel.php
```

---

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \stix\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \stix\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],
```

Now laravel will automatically include X-CRSF-TOKEN for every request made within the web middleware group. Hope this helps.